# Launch inactive app with URL scheme

Tags: ios, swift

I was able to add capability to launch my iOS app from URL (i.e.:  myapp://xxxx) if the app is already running. However, if I close the app (crash it) and click on the URL, it only opens the app in the rootView instead of calling the `func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool` method. Any ideas? In addition, it seems the only way I can test it is on an actual device and close the app, hence I can't use Xcode to debug.

Comment: what are you doing in that method to decipher the scheme to send users to a particular view? If you aren't doing anything, or it's not set up properly it will go to root view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use "application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool" function to get url which called to open app, so modify application delegate to become like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    //any thing need to initialise app
    if let url = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey] as? NSURL {
        let sourceApp = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String
        let annotation = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsAnnotationKey] as? AnyObject
        self.application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApp, annotation: annotation)
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mousavian, that worked! Xcode complained about casting, so I added `as AnyObject?` to annotation line. On a related note, from website, I can launch the app using `myapp://xxx`, but only if the app is already installed. Is there a way to direct user to AppStore to download and go to specific deep linked page after download?

Comment: I added casting to Answer. If it satisfies you please mark it as accepted answer.
There is separate scheme for iTunes App Store, something like this:
let id = "948397575" // You app id here
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=\\(id)&mt=8uo=6")!)